# Python, most efficient structure for an n key lookup

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, search, data-structures

I have a set of data that needs to be looked up based on keys as such:

```
#  fk is a comparsion function
#  Keys go from 1 to n
#  Assume that this is done whilst going through rows that have said keys and item inside

if f1(key1, val1) and f2(key2, val2)... and fn(keyn, valn):
    return item
```

What would be the most efficient data structure & algorithm ensemble in python for doing this kind of lookup. Preferably present in the default libraries or in a well-maintained library. Currently I'm looking for something similar to boost's multi-map but I assume there may be a better way.

In my case I have exactly 3 keys and the comparison functions are '<', '>' and '==' but I'm asking this for the general case since I assume similar question may pop up (or may have popped up before and I can't find them).

Comment: I don't see any comparison done here - only pairs of key/value...

Comment: Can your functions be in a list? can your keys be in a list?

Comment: @khelwood Yes and yes, I don't see why not

Comment: @alfasin What I wrote is a generic case, which assumes fk is a function that return a boolean if given a key and a value

Comment: So you could write `if all(f(key, value) for (f,key,value) in zip(functions, keys, values))`. That might be easier/clearer than writing them out explicitly. I'm kind of unclear on what you're after.

Comment: Yes... I guess that would be a more "concise" way of writing things. Personally I think in pseudocode this notation is more clear here, but the question is not around how to express this (It's rather easy to express using a custom lookup function in a map or list, but how to do it efficiently without explicitly writting a mutliple data structures optimal for the search function of each key... e.g. by using a library that could generate such an ensemble of data structures)

Comment: The question is not very clear. Could snippet would have been better,

Comment: @Amit Tripathi How can I post a code snipet referring to a generic algorithm question ? Would the pseudocode posted by khelwood be easier to read in your opinion ? Otherwise please do tell how exactly should I put the question into code, I'm open to editing it

Comment: @George If i have to ask this question I would have asked "I have set of keys from 1...n and set of values from 1...n how to compare keys on the same index for <, > or == values"
I am just saying going round and round around the question wastes everybody's time. Also It's not clear if fk is a comparison function they why there are different f's

Comment: @Amit Tripathi Because a comparsion function can be behave differently depending on data type and as can be seen the values and keys have various data type. (E.g '<' implemented on ClassA may be complete different than '<' implemented on ClassB)... think of fk as just a function returning True or False when given two values, there's an infinity of function that do that

Comment: @George "think of fk as just a function returning True or False when given two values," - but you're not passing "two values" you're passing a "key" and a "value" - that's exactly what makes your question unclear. Do you compare a key to a value ? if that's the case they are both values - what's the point of naming one of them "key" ?

Comment: "What I wrote is a generic case, which assumes fk is a function that return a boolean if given a key and a value" - what does that even mean??? "if a key and a value" - what ???

Comment: Is it the case that you start with three functions and three keys then need to apply them to a table of a million rows, each row having three values? What is item?

Comment: @Paddy3118 Yes, in order to find the exact matching row in the table, however I may need an algorithm that can do the same thing for , say 5 functions and 5 keys or 2 functions and 2 keys

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have lists of functions and corresponding arguments

```
functions = [f1, f2, f3]
keyvalues = [(key1, val1), (key2, val2), (key3, val3)]
```

You can zip the two together and apply the functions to the arguments with a generator expression, which becomes an argument to the `all` function:

```
if all(f(*args) for (f, args) in zip(functions, keyvalues)):
```

Comment: Yes, however this would be highly inefficient [always O(n) expensive operations] if my list of values grows bigger. Henece why I'm asking of a library that can optimize this (e.g. that generates a data structures based on the types of f to arrange the data, so that any search that can be done in O(1) time, such as looking for key==value is handled in O(1) time, leaving behind smaller data structures which have to have lookups done using O(logn) functions... leaving behind data structures for which the lookup functions are O(n))

Comment: You are using Python 3; `zip` returns an iterator that produces elements on demand. Further, `all` short-circuits: if the first function evaluates to `False`, it immediately returns `False` without consuming the rest of the iterator returned by `zip`.

Comment: If you were using Python 2, the only change you would need to make would be to replace `zip` with `itertools.izip`.

Comment: Benchmarking this in practice (With my usecase which is one == against a string and two < > comparisons against and int), the whole list approach (on a dataset of ~3 million values) is order of magnitude slower than having a map (which contains the values that are to be compared via ==) and than splits of into multiple smaller lists depending on the results of ==. Your approach may be alright for few searches or small datasets.

Comment: You might want to show a concrete example of the types of function you are actually using. You keep saying you have 3 functions, and implied that you also had 3 sets of values to apply them to. Now you have 3+-million values? Add your benchmark code to the question, and we might have a better idea of what you want.

Comment: What I want, as I said before, Is a code that can do a complex key lookup on an arbitrary data structure with keys of different types and different lookup functions per keys, which can have < O(n) complexity if the lookup functions allow for it. I'n other words what I want could be said to be something alike this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost/container/multimap.html But I doubt that helps if you don't know C++, and I can't find a good multimap in ptyhon (hence why i'm asking, multimap isn't ncessarily the best term, so I thought giving the general usage example is better

Comment: Also, posting my snippet of code here would be irrelevant, I already know how it can be optimized for searching and I've already did it, I was hoping to find a more generic solution in case I need it in other situations and to make the code easier to understand

Comment: @George what you describe in your last two comments has nothing to do with multimap. Your question is totally unclear - as was mentioned by a few members already!

Comment: @alfasin A multimap can be defined as a structure for lookup based on mutliple keys, however I do agree the question seems to be unclear to most people looking at it... I would argue that given time someone may answer the question, but since the SO model is a democratic one and this question seem to be unclear to the average I will close it. I'm unsure if there is a way to make it "more clear", if I think of one I may open a new question.

Comment: You can make it more clear by showing the benchmark that makes this solution untenable.

Comment: How can I show benchmarks for a problem on a theoretical case :( ? Or do you want me to "show" you that using a complex search function on a list is more expensive than first looking up a smaller range of values in hash map and then searching the smaller list (which is the optimization that can be done in my case, but writing an algoirhtm to generalize that is obviously a bit harder)... because I think the former should be self evident.

Comment: "Benchmarking this in practice... the whole list approach (on a dataset of ~3 million values) is order of magnitude slower than having a map". *That*. You claim to have run a test that showed a order of magnitude slowdown; we want to see that.

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import partial

from operator import lt, le, eq, ne, ge, gt
from pprint import pprint as pp

def data_extract(funcs, keys, table):
    assert len(funcs) == len(keys) == len(table[0]), \
           'Error: incompatable data sizes'
    # substitutes for *first* param
    pfuncs = [partial(f, k) for f, k in zip(funcs, keys)] 
    return [row for row in table 
            if all(p(value) 
                   for p, value in zip(pfuncs, row))]

def skip(a, b):
    return True

tbl = [[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [4, 6, 8],
       [10, 12, 14],
       # ... millions
       ]

fn = [ge, le, skip]
ks = [12, 6, None]

ans = data_extract(fn, ks, tbl)
pp(ans)  # [[4, 6, 8], [10, 12, 14]]
```

Hopefully the above is a correct interpretation of your problem. I cannot work out how to use a dict to help if the `funcs` and/or `keys` are going to change every time you call the function.

`skip` is just a way of stating that data in that column of the table is "don't care".